# VB.Net remove whitespace with regex excluding content inside <script>

Tags: javascript, regex, vb.net, whitespace

I want to reduce the size out my HTML output stream by removing all empty lines and whitespace. However I'm not very good at regex and the pattern I have seems to remove more than wanted e.g. whole script blocks. How can I make sure that  blocks are kept in tact?

This is what I have so far:

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, ">\s+<", "><", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

Comment: what about `html = Regex.Replace(html, "\s+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled)`

Comment: Rule 1, never parse HTML with regex.  Rule 2, if you want to use regex to parse HTML, see rule 1.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the amount of time you'll save in the download (in comparison to the length of time to process the HTML on each request) will be at best negligible - and at worst, actually take longer.  Sounds like you're worrying about nothing

Comment: freefaller, I've heard about that. But how would I garuantee to have no whitespace in ASP.Net when I have no clue where it's being added by the engine?

Comment: Why is it so important to remove whitespace?  (If you want somebody to receive notification of your comment, you must put the @ sign before their name, see the [help for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) )

Comment: Post some html generated code (or link) so we can see how it looks

Comment: **Check this link**: http://omari-o.blogspot.com/2009/09/aspnet-white-space-cleaning-with-no.html

Comment: @freefaller thanks for pointing out how to address people. I have measured the time to apply the regex and it's 16ms on a 841kB HTML file which is being reduced to 806kB. I find this performance quite acceptable (besides your eligible Rule 1 which I'm not sure to break yet).

Comment: @LGSon This sounds interesting. However I can't find the download to the example project. Do you happen to have it at your hands? Thanks

Comment: Here is a GitHub with another minifyer: https://github.com/deanhume/html-minifier/blob/master/ViewMinifier/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for conditional regex. [Look at examples here Regex Tutorial If-Then-Else](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

There are different regex for different systems (.Net, Python, etc)